# A very simple for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

Why does this:

```
for i in reader:
        for j in empsTbl:
            if i[0] == j.inmptl_wiw_userid:
                print "Match"
```

print over 500 results

And this:

```
for i in empsTbl:
        for j in reader:
            if j[0] == i.inmptl_wiw_userid:
                print "Match"
```

print no results?

Comment: This can't be answered without knowing what *exactly* the values of `reader` and `empsTbl` are when each loop is executed. `i` and `j` are also not great names for loop variables that aren't integer indices.

Comment: reader is a csv reader which has around 500 rows and will print them all if looped on its own. empsTbl is an oracle database table which has 700 rows and will print them all if looped on its own. The first piece of code actually prints far more than 500 times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like your `reader` is a generator, that can be read only once. Maybe a file reader?

In the first case you read it only once and compare each value to all elements of `empsTbl`, which is apparently a list (or tuple or set or dict, i.e. can be read as much as you want).

In the second case, you read it completely while being at the first item of `empsTbl` (apparently does not match it if nothing is printed) and then with the second item of `empsTbl` it cannot be read again (i.e. the file is read over).

**UPDATE**: With this number of records you can copy everything into Python lists which can be iterated over and over (set/dictionary would be probably even better, as they offer you much faster lookup times)

Maybe something like this:

```
readerSet = set(i[0] for i in reader)

for j in empsTbl:
    if j.inmptl_wiw_userid in readerSet:
        print "Match"
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer that we really need to know more about what `reader` and `empsTbl` are. But one possibility that springs to mind is that `reader` is a generator. In that case, iterating over it in the inner loop doesn't work, because the generator is exhausted in the first iteration of the outer loop, leaving the inner loop empty I'm all subsequent iterations of the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

If `empsTbl` and `reader` are different lists, and contain different types of elements, then `j[0]` and `i[0]` should most probably be different things.

That should explain the difference, like the "mixing oranges and apples" old story.

But of course, that is just part of the answer, since we only can see part of the question ;o)